# How avoid my external HD regularly disconnecting and reconnecting automatically?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have a Seagate Expansion Drive 1.5TB external HD connected on my PC with Windows 7 ultimate.

The problem is the HD is regularly disconnecting and reconnecting automatically when the HD is idle?

What can I do to finish this inconvenient process?

Thanks!

Comment: Disable USB selective suspend options. You will find them somewhere in Power settings.

Answer (score 1):

My guesses are the cables connecting your 1.5 TB Hard Drive and PC is damaged, power supply is faulty or the USB port is loose.

My suggestions are:

1. Try connecting a different Hard Drive and see if it still has the same issues. if it does, have your PC cleaned and try to see if the USB port is faulty.
2. Use a different cable to connect your 1.5 TB Hard Drive.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the hard drive is automatically doing this.  Was there any software that Seagate provided with the drive?

[This](http://seagate.custkb.com/seagate/crm/selfservice/search.jsp?DocId=205911&NewLang=en&Hilite=) is directly from their website with a similar issue only on the MAC.  Looks useful to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Hard Disk Sentinel](http://www.hdsentinel.com) to adjust the setting for the drive's APM (Advanced Power Management) and set it to NOT standby on idle.  Maybe the disk is powering down for whatever reason and this is causing the disconnect, and it would operate normally if it just remained on like a regular disk.